# Laravel Deployment on shared hosting gives "Directory index forbidden by Options directive"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

Below is my `.htaccess` in main Laravel root and `/public`

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try removing the `Options -Indexes` line.  It's responsible for not showing a list of files if someone hits a folder which doesn't have an index.  I don't think it's necessary, just good to have.

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting's apache config `document root` is Laravel root. But Laravel haven't index.php inside root folder. You can just leave .htaccess in `/public` as is but in root folder you need change .htaccess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```